# Max Size for SemanticImport?

Tags: import, dataset

Does anyone know what the max data size for SemanticImport is? 
I have a 4GB data file I need to break down, just don't know how small I have to break it.

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, is your data a 2D array?  If you have that much data, you are better off determining the data types beforehand and reading it in as a stream.  Are the data types the same for all the lines of the file?  If so, could you paste the first ~20 lines or so of the file?

Comment: It's not a 2D array sadly, it's a large excel document. Yes, I can determine data types. And if not SemanticImport, is there any other way I can get the data in?

Comment: Make a small example file out of the excel document, 0.5mb instead of 4GB, and post it on dropbox or something.  4GB is huge for one file usually